# I am getting "ERROR: Application not supported by this buildpack!" while pushing the laravel app

Tags: laravel, git, heroku, git-push

I have made a BotMan app in the phpstorm platform. Whenever I push to heroku master though I added procfile, I am getting an error like this:

```
Counting objects: 370, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (339/339), done.
Writing objects: 100% (370/370), 571.47 KiB | 3.38 MiB/s, done.
Total 370 (delta 148), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz
remote:        
remote:  !     ERROR: Application not supported by this buildpack!
remote:  !     
remote:  !     The 'heroku/php' buildpack is set on this application, but was
remote:  !     unable to detect a PHP codebase.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     A PHP app on Heroku requires a 'composer.json' at the root of
remote:  !     the directory structure, or an 'index.php' for legacy behavior.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy a PHP application, ensure that one
remote:  !     of these files is present at the top level directory.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
remote:  !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
remote:  !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information, refer to the following documentation:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation
remote: 
remote: 
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to finproj.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/finproj.git
 !  remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/finproj.git'`
```

I heard it has something to do with git repo. I didn't understand what that means. What's the fix for this?

Comment: The error says it doesn't recognize your app as a PHP application. Do you have a `composer.json` file? And is that file being committed in git?

Comment: what are the commands that you've tried that resulted that error?

Comment: Now i am getting a different error. it says something about yarn